# Image not rendering when appending it with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am attempting to append a `<img>` element made in JavaScript into a `<td>`. What happens is the area where the image is meant to be expands slightly, but the image doesn't appear. the console gives me no error and i am truly baffled. Here is ALL of my code (Because i dont know what is causing the problem). I am also using the normalize css file and jquery in a local area.

Javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
    var turn = 1;
    document.title = "First Player";
    var coolDown = 'False';
    var makeScreen = function(){
        var height = $(window).height();
        var width = $(window).width();
        $('#screen').height(height);
        $('#screen').width(height);
        var extraSpace = width - height;
        var halfOfExtraSpace = extraSpace / 2;
        $('#screen').css("left", halfOfExtraSpace);
    };
    var handleClickOne = function(){
        drawImage('one');
    };
    var handleClickTwo = function(){
        drawImage('two');
    };
    var drawImage = function(section){
        if (turn == 1){
            if (coolDown == 'False'){
                drawCircle(section);
                turn = 2;
                document.title = "Second Player";
                coolDown = 'True';
            };
        };
        if (turn == 2){
            if (coolDown == 'False'){
                drawCross(section);
                turn = 1;
                document.title = "First Player";
                coolDown = 'True';
            };
        };
        coolDown = 'False';
    };
    var drawCircle = function(section){
        alert('circle')
        var circle = document.createElement("img");
        circle.innerHTML = "src='Circle.png'"
        $("#one").append(circle);
    };
    var drawCross = function(section){
        alert('cross')
    };
    makeScreen();
    var one = document.getElementById('one');
    one.addEventListener('click', handleClickOne);
    var two = document.getElementById('two');
    two.addEventListener('click', handleClickTwo);

};
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <title>JavaScript Interaction Test.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="screen">
            <tr>
                <td id="one"></td>
                <td id="two"></td>
                <td id="three"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="four"></td>
                <td id="five"></td>
                <td id="six"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="seven"></td>
                <td id="eight"></td>
                <td id="nine"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50)
}

td{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: black;
}
#screen{
    position: absolute;
    left:0cm;
    top:0cm;
}
```

Before replying or voting please take in consideration i am still a partial noob to some aspects of JavaScript and please take in consideration that i dont know everything you do even the basic things so dont down-vote me because it was a simple question.

Also, i have looked around the internet and stackoverflow and found no awnser thats relevent to helping me in the situation i am in now.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   var circle = document.createElement("img");
        circle.innerHTML = "src='Circle.png'"
```

should be:

```
   var circle = document.createElement("img");
        circle.src = 'Circle.png';
```

The circle is an image so it doesn't have any property called innerHTML. It uses the 'src' attribute however.

Comment: Thanks alot! It draws the circle now... But i'm now having the problem that the image completely distorts the entire of the table, more specificly, amplifiying the table segmenent that its placed in... is there a way that i can draw the circle in and it not interacting with any other element?

Comment: Tables are elastic by nature, they will stretch to fit whatever content you place in them. You can provide a set dimensions for the image though.

Comment: I mean, I want it so the circle dosent interact with the rest of the table AT ALL

Comment: Even when i set my circle.height / width, the whole table still distorts

Comment: Can you post something I can take a look at?

Comment: So this table cell is now ~226px x ~226px. Unless all your other table cells are the same dimensions, then yes it will look distorted.

Comment: How can i make it so all the tables are the same size?

Comment: THis is what i am seeing when circle.height and circle.width are at 26 http://prntscr.com/689lku

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71419/discussion-between-rob-r-and-jammeh-carr).